# how to generate an enum comparison in an odata query string with a kendo ui for angular FilterDescriptor

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-web-api, odata, kendo-ui-angular2

I have an ASP WebApi OData v6 project accepting odata http queries.

Is there a way to use a kendo-angular-ui [FilterDescriptor](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/FilterDescriptor/) to perform an Equal (eq) operation to match an enum ? My goal is to populate a [State](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/State/) that will be used in conjunction with [toODataString](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/toODataString/) method.

The problem is that the OData specification require enum to be fully qualified.

For instance:

> SomeField eq My.Fully.Quallified'EnumValue'

*(note the single quotes only placed around the actual value of the Enum)*

But I can not find a way to describe that the value put in my filter descriptor is not to be handled as a string but as an enum.

The filter descriptor looks like the following:

```
const myFilterDescriptor = <FilterDescriptor> {
    field:'SomeField',
    operator:'eq',
    value:'My.Fully.Quallified.EnumValue'
};
```

Without surprise this FilterDescriptor will generate the following incorrect odata text:

> SomeField eq 'My.Fully.Quallified.EnumValue'

*(single quotes are misplaced)*

Another possibility, is to get rid of the enum text part of the odata segment. I mean the problem would gone if instead of passing a text to the FilterDescriptor value I could just pass the enum numerical value.

i.e.:

```
const myFilterDescriptor = <FilterDescriptor> {
    field:'SomeField',
    operator:'eq',
    value:123
};
```

This does not seems allowed by the default web api odata HttpConfiguration.
I found the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34874182/4306452) proposing the usage of **EnableEnumPrefixFree** which seem to have disappeared as of web api odata v6. [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41041475/4306452) related to WebApi odata v6 suggest a custom implementation in order to mimic EnableEnumPrefixFree, which I didn't get to work.

So to summarize, **how could I easily generate an enum comparison in an odata query string with a kendo ui for angular FilterDescriptor ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working as described [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/816) and [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/OData60/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/UriParserExtension/EnumPrefixFreeTest.cs) :

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    "odata",
    "odata",
    builder =>
      builder.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => GetEdmModel())
            .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp =>
                            ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("odata", config))
            .AddService<ODataUriResolver>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new StringAsEnumResolver()));
```

The trick is to manually register the StringAsEnumResolver service in the configuration. This is the way to configure WebApi odata layer as from version 6 [they now favour DI](https://odata.github.io/WebApi/13-04-DependencyInjection/) instead of the previous configuration methods (such as EnableEnumPrefixFree).

So the following odata comparison is working now:

> SomeField eq 'EnumValue'

*(note that using numeric value (such as `SomeField eq 123` ) does not work)*

Therefor the FilterDescripror could be used this way:

```
const myFilterDescriptor = <FilterDescriptor> {
    field:'SomeField',
    operator:'eq',
    value:'EnumValue'
};
```